# Parse Json string to Html elements

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a Json string like this : `[{"Row_id":"1","Name":"AmoghEngineers","Category":"Dress","Subcategory":"jeans","District":"7","Location":"India","Plan":"Gold","ProductOrService":"Product","Email":"mymail@gmail.com","About":"goodone","Phone":"98675433","Registration_confirmed":"Yes"}]` .

And i need to parse these data to the html field elements ,for eg: i want to set the Name to a input field `$("#businessName").val(Name)`. How can i do this ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWZxA/2/)**

```
$("#businessName").val(jsonObjArray[0].Name)
```

**Edit** If you have this in string you can use $.parseJSON

```
jsonObjArray= $.parseJSON('[{"Row_id":"1","Name":"AmoghEngineers","Category":"Dress","Subcategory":"jeans","District":"7","Location":"India","Plan":"Gold","ProductOrService":"Product","Email":"mymail@gmail.com","About":"goodone","Phone":"98675433","Registration_confirmed":"Yes"}]');    
$("#businessName").val(jsonObjArray[0].Name);
```

Comment: var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result); alert(obj[0].Name)This works , but is it good to use indexing on the jsonObj ??

Comment: You have array of objects so you need to use index, name of variable is confusing it would be jsonObjArray, check my updated answer.

Comment: okay fine ,let me workout

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = '[{"Row_id":"1","Name":"AmoghEngineers","Category":"Dress","Subcategory":"jeans","District":"7","Location":"India","Plan":"Gold","ProductOrService":"Product","Email":"mymail@gmail.com","About":"goodone","Phone":"98675433","Registration_confirmed":"Yes"}]'

var json_data = JSON.parse(data)
$("#businessName").val(json_data[0].Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to call like this way

var jsonresponse_obj = JSON.parse(response);

```
jsonresponse_obj.Row_id to get value of row id and soo on
```